# IMAP Server - SslStream AuthenticateAsClient - Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#

So i'm sending a TcpClient connect request to mail.mysupplyworld.com:993 and it connects fine, and I then get the TcpClients NetworkStream and wrap it to an SslStream.

All works fine, except once I attempt to SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient on it.
It immediately responds with: Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream.

From other answers on here it seems to be an issue with the SSL Protocol used, however in my code, I have it using every protocol available in 4.7.1 yet it still occurs

For example I use:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;
```

Aswell as for the AuthenticateAsClient:

```
((SslStream)_tcpClientNetworkStream).AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, new X509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Ssl2 | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
```

Yet it still fails.
Are any of you able to connect to it using the settings I used above?

Code example (Run this and it should return the same error):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;    
((SslStream)new TcpClient("mail.mysupplyworld.com", 993).GetStream()).AuthenticateAsClient("mail.mysupplyworld.com", new X509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Ssl2 | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12, false)
```

This returns an error with the AuthenticateAsClient.
Do note, that code block works for other IMAP mail servers just fine

Comment: If you are trying to connect to a mail server the FROM email account and the credentials (user) must use the same.

Comment: @jdweng Read, im just attempting to connect, I can "connect" but I need to SslStream Authenticate before doing anything, which im unable to do if you read above

Comment: You are failing the AuthenticateAsClient().  Are you getting this after you login to Server with credentials or when you are login with credentials.  I usually recommend using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see when you are actually failing.  The FIN message is the TCP connection closing.  The connection could be closing when you are sending the credentials, but the c# is not reporting the closing.  Then when you try to Authenticate you are getting an error because the connection was closed.

Comment: @jdweng I literally connect via TcpClient(host, port).GetStream() wrap it with SslStream and then authenticate as shown above. Nothing else is done in between

Comment: I usually refer back to one of the codeprojects like the followng : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429144/Simple-Instant-Messenger-with-SSL-Encryption-in-Cs

Comment: @jdweng Please stop pointlessly refering me to unrelated stuff when you clearly dont understand the issue or even bothered to attempt the code I posted.

Comment: I have help lots of people to connect to email using smtp and know all the issues.  There is very little info on using SMTP with a mysupplyworld email account.   My recommendation is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and connect to site using vendor app and capture results.  Then do same with your app and compare the differences.

Comment: @jdweng ok m8, jesus, first of all this is IMAP, not SMTP... your recommending me the 2 most popular tools and you dont even know what they are for, fiddler is for web requests and wireshark is packet capture (can be used, but not optimized for it), please stop being text support.

Comment: Someone please purge these comments, they are useless as f

Comment: @jdweng Clearly yet u dont even understand a clear difference between an IMAP question and an SMTP question, please stop commenting.

Comment: IMAP is just another IP protocol.  Wireshark and Fiddler both can capture any type IP Protocol.  SMTP uses TCP as transport layer.  There are two basic types of IP messages : UDP and TCP.  I am qualified to teach the course so do not question my ability on this subject.

Comment: @jdweng Show me how to capture IMAP data using Fiddler then please

Comment: Purge these comments someone, they are as useless and uneducated that I have seen in a long time